# cd into directory with git lfs files takes very long

Tags: zsh, io, git-log

I have a (data) repository with ~50GB of data, split into <10 subdirs with files of 100 to 1000MB each. The repository is saved on a SSD, the workstation has 16 CPU Cores and 64GB of RAM.

All files are stored via `git lfs`.

Sometimes, when I `cd` into this repository, I have lots of `git lfs filter-process` workers blocking the terminal for >=60 seconds.

1. Why is that, given that I just `cd` into the repository? `git lfs filter-process` converts between pointers and actual data -> when I `cd` into the repository I should not trigger converting since I did not do a `git lfs pull` or something?
2. Even if it needs to check some pointers and convert, what could cause this process to take >=60 seconds? The system's M2 NVMe SSD is fine (benchmarked reading/writing speed -> above 3GB/s).

Comment: Which shell? Do you have a git prompt setup? Is `cd` an alias or function for something more than `cd`?

Comment: I am using `zsh`, I will test later on with `bash` and `fish` as well. `cd` is not an alias.

Comment: However, good point @muru, most probably `zsh` is triggering `git lfs` then, right?

Comment: If you have a prompt that shows git status, probably.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue occasionally. But after I issue `git status` command, there is no delay

Comment: Whilst that may be interesting, it doesn't answer the question of _what is causing the delay_.

Comment: This correctly solves the problem and should be a "chosen answer" as it's the only answer here.